# Kendo UI Grid binded to OData: how to get the request URL?

Tags: kendo-ui, odata

I have a Kendo Grid binded to a remote OData endpoint.
How can I capture the request URL sent to the remote endpoint in one of the javascript events, like the DataSource's onRequestStart ?

this gives me the filter/sort objects

```
var filter = this.filter();
var sort = this.sort();
```

But I want the actual URL, like

```
http://..serviceroot/table1?$filter=....
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way is via beforeSend:

```
   transport: {
     read: {
        url: "http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Northwind.svc/Orders",
        beforeSend: function(e, request) {
          console.log(request.url);
        }
     }
   }
```

Comment: This seemed backwards from the way I was originally approaching it, but works just fine.

Comment: any idea how in that context I could do something like put the request on the dataSource as a property called something like "lastGet" so I can use it from code outside the function?

Comment: Thank you very much, I've been looking for this!